# Stop Blender trying to connect online

Tags: settings

I have discovered that when my internet connection is disabled, Blender loads up much faster. I would like to find a way to make blender think that my internet connection is disabled, when it isn't. This way it wouldn't matter why it's trying to connect online (e.g. some addon checking for updates or any other reason).

After hours of trying to figure out how to make blender load quickly, this is what I've found:

1. Blocking outbound blender connections via firewall works, but it is still much slower to load vs when the internet connection is disabled.
2. Removing addons that might try to connect online helps to speed up blender loading, but blender always loads faster when the internet connection is disabled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: running a VPN connection stops blender trying to connect online for some reason (so possibly this is related to some proxy setting). However, I would like to find a solution to make Blender not even try to connect in the first place, which is what happens if the internet connection is disabled.

Comment: Aren't you just using a third party addon that connects to the internet for some data, typically an online asset manager like Blenderkit or something? Because AFAIK Blender is designed to not use anything online out of the box.

Comment: Blender, as a principle, does not have any modules that check or need internet connection to work. It is very unlikely that this slowdown you're talking about is due to Blender itself; probably a rogue addon--find out which one and disable it. If you're right and internet connection slows down Blender, it'd be a bug (report it); if it's not a bug, then it's a general question about software-internet relations on Windows, neither of which is something we can answer here.

Comment: Yes some addons must be causing this online checkup since after removing all addons Blender loads normally/quickly. I though that because those scripts run within Blender, there must be a blender setting/python line that blocks this call, since it doesnt try to do this when internet is disabled. In other words, instead of constantly trying to keep track of which addon/python file has one line that checks fonts or updates or whatever it is, Id like Blender just to not check anything online for any reason. Is this not possible?

Comment: @Downat3D I guess not that it's possible, since Blender itself is build to work without any network connection - at least, my resource monitor shows no network traffic when starting up Blender. So why should they implement a general network blocking function if there are only some (third party) addons that would use the connection? And I guess it's a functionality of the addon that the developers supposed to be a good/necessary feature, why should they want it to be restricted...?

Comment: i agree with L0Lock and had also some issues with BlenderKit (which not only was buggy and has thrown errors) but also displays annoying popups...so i just disabled it

Comment: Thanks everyone for contributing. I was hoping there was some hidden way to disable any internet connections within Blender as a way to customise the user experience and prevent some random stuff and libraries downloading. I guess that kind of thing is something left to the OS itself. I just feel like Blender must first listen to some code that tells it to check online, and therefore there should be something that controls whether it listens or not. Even if this exists, it's probably not in some python settings file.